# Change width of thead ,tbody ,td dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I applied this property in .css file on this table [image: records] and records are 9.

```
   .fixed tbody td, thead th {
    width: 5.2%;
    float: left;
    }
```

Like when I have 4 column width must be 23.2% , when we have 5 columns width must be 18.2%, when I have 6 columns width must be 16.2% , when 7 width must be 14.2%. when columns are 8 width must be 12.2% . and maybe more columns come so I dont know but how can I manage this width ? I saw questions but they show that width must decrease or increase sequential. So what is best solution now ?

Comment: Why would the amount of records (which affects `height`) need to cause a change to `width`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus width increase or decrease when number of column increase or decrease. I am not concerned with height as I handled it using overflow.

Comment: But, your question asks about record count, not column count.

Comment: You can create class for table based on number of columns/rows and just use `<table class="col-6 row-6">`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I corrected sorry.

Comment: @MForm using bootstrap ? Is it possible how ?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. You are confusing rows and columns. Records are rows. *"Like when I have 4 column width must be 23.2% , when we have 5 records width must be 18.2%, "*

Comment: Why not just set the `table` width and let the columns adjust themselves?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette how it is possible ?  I dont know much about it. can you make a small example please?

Comment: @ScottMarcus In Image I attached , I have 8 coloums so my width is 12,2% . when It will 9 width would be 10.2 .

Comment: Yes, I know, but your *question* still talks about **records**. Records are rows.

Comment: who can I assign width to this using javascript ( .fixed tbody td)   ? like as we give to id like this ( document.getElementbyid('id') )  so how can I apply on ( .fixed tbody td)  ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to set equal width to each columns and don't know how many columns there is.
The width should then be the table width divided by the column amount.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // The table to work on.
  var table = $("table.fixed")

  // Get table width
  var tableWidth = table.width();

  // Get the collection of the td on the first row.
  var firstRowTdCollection = table.find("tr").first().find("td");

  // Get the column count.
  var columnCount = firstRowTdCollection.length;

  // Calculate the width based on table width divided by the column amount.
  var widthToApply = tableWidth / columnCount;

  // Apply the calculated width on the first row (Not necessary on the other rows)
  firstRowTdCollection.each(function(){
    $(this).width(widthToApply);
  });
});
```

Comment: .fixed is just class name.

Comment: Really? And it is not possitionned as fixed? What a confusing classname...

Comment: who can I assign width to this using javascript ( .fixed tbody td)   ? like as we give to id like this ( document.getElementbyid('id') )  so how can I apply on ( .fixed tbody td)  ?

Comment: Here is a jQuery way to calculate the `width` and make all columns equal.